# Azure SQL DB: Can't create table because it already exists, can't drop or write to table because it doesn't exist

Tags: azure-sql-database, drop-table

I have an Azure SQL DB database that I am copying data into from a source database using SSIS. My SSIS package for one table fails because it can't write to or create a specific table name (it is important to keep the same table names as in the source database). I attempted to address the problem via an SQL query, but

```
CREATE TABLE [schemaname].[tablename]
```

returns:

```
There is already an object named 'tablename' in the database.
```

and

```
DROP TABLE [tablename]
```

returns:

```
Cannot drop the table 'tablename', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
```

I have had a look at a few posts where other people have had similar problems, but the solutions offered are either not possible in this situation or do not work: I am already accessing the database with the admin account, and there are no tables with the same name as this in any other schema either. Dropping the table if it exists gives the same error, and FLUSH TABLES seems to be MySQL-specific so does not work. Because it is an Azure database, I can't access the back-end filesystem, and the database is too large to easily move or copy anywhere else.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how to resolve this?

Comment: You need to wait for some time after that the deleted database would be *completely* deleted, this is what I have observed in Azure SQL database.

Comment: I deleted the table yesterday but the error is still occurring today, and I need to get the package built by the end of the day. Do you know how long it usually takes to recognise that the table doesn't exist?

Comment: Why are you including the schema name in one but not the other? Can you try DROP but add the schema in?

Comment: I tried both, neither worked. Eventually it let me create the table again, but I had to wait over 24 hours after dropping it, it was very odd.

Comment: I have the same problem.  I have only waited 10 minutes so far.  I really want to use the same name, but I can't wait 24+ hours :-(.